# How can I sort and concat a csv file in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, sorting

I'm currently in a project and I need to work with a lot of CSV files, which are filled with data something like this:

```
    CSV1.csv

      A      B     C     D    ...
    1 1980  1     0.9   0.8
    2 2003  0.9   0.8   0.2
    3 1665  0.7   0.2   0.4
    4 1982  0.6   1     0.2
   ...

     CSV2.csv
      A      E     F     G   ...
    1 1665  1     0.4   1
    2 1980  0.4   0.8   0.6
    3 2003  0.1   0.3   0.9
    4 1982  0.3   1     0.6
   ...
```

All of the CSV files have the same values in the `A` column, but are disorganized. I am importing all the files like this:

```
path = r"/Users/.../folder/"
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.CSV")
all_csv = (pd.read_csv(f, sep=',') for f in all_files)
df_merged   = pd.concat(all_csv, axis=1, ignore_index=False)
```

It gets merged, but the dataframe is disorganized.

This way is not correct to sort with `df_merged.sort()` because there is not a column with the same order at `A`. I know that I can manually import each one of the csv files and apply a `.sort()`, but those are 394 csv files...

I feel like something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32998337/how-can-i-read-and-sort-a-csv-file-in-python) might be applicable in a large import of CSV files, but I don't know how to call a code line **before** the dataframe combination gets made (`all_csv` is a generator object).

---

P.S. at the end I execute to eliminate repeated `A` columns:

```
df_merged = df_merged.loc[:, ~df_merged.columns.duplicated()]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Alignment can be obtained by setting A as the index.
2. Using a list of dataframes is not appealing as this can take a lot of memory.

   - **solution 1:** Build the other dataframes in the loop

   ```
   import pandas as pd

   path = r"/Users/.../folder/"
   all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.CSV")

   df = pd.read_csv(all_files[0], sep=',').set_index('A')
   for f in all_files[1:]:
       dfs = pd.read_csv(f, sep=',').set_index('A')
       df = pd.concat([df, dfs], axis=1)
   ```

   - **solution 2:** Keep the generator and use `functools.reduce`

   ```
   import pandas as pd
   from functools import reduce

   path = r"/Users/.../folder/"
   all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.CSV")

   def_gen = (pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(fn), sep='\s+').set_index('A') for fn in all_files)
   df = reduce(lambda df, d: pd.concat([df, d], axis=1), def_gen)
   ```

   `df`:

   ```
           B    C    D    E    F    G
   A                                 
   1665  0.7  0.2  0.4  1.0  0.4  1.0
   1980  1.0  0.9  0.8  0.4  0.8  0.6
   1982  0.6  1.0  0.2  0.3  1.0  0.6
   2003  0.9  0.8  0.2  0.1  0.3  0.9
   ```

Personally, I would take the easy path ("solution 1") and add some logging to identify where there will be an import error. Because in real world data is rarely clean and well formatted.

Comment: Thank you, I like what you are doing... but in the first option, how could I select for set_index('A') the first column if it may not have always the same name?

Comment: @Juank, to concatenate, join, merge etc. you need to have at least a key. either the key is explicit (has a name) or at least the key is implicit (first 'field '). Can you provide a subset (or mockup) of your data,, as it seems that CSV1.csv and CSV2.csv do not match exactly  your data (i.e. they ave an common field named 'A') ans confirm that you whant to align on the first field.

Comment: @Juank, Yes the code works. But  frankly, I would take the easy path ("solution 1") and add some logging to identify where there will be an import error. Because in real world data is rarely clean and well formatted..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using concat, you should merge each dataframe together:

```
df = all_csv[0]
for csv in all_csv[1:]:
    df = df.merge(csv)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
      A    B    C    D    E    F    G
0  1980  1.0  0.9  0.8  0.4  0.8  0.6
1  2003  0.9  0.8  0.2  0.1  0.3  0.9
2  1665  0.7  0.2  0.4  1.0  0.4  1.0
3  1982  0.6  1.0  0.2  0.3  1.0  0.6
```

Note: you need to make `all_csv` a list instead of a generator:

```
all_csv = [pd.read_csv(f, sep=',') for f in all_files]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think it worked. In order to apply what you said I had to convert the all_csv from object generator to line, like this: 

all_csv = list(all_csv)

Comment: A better way to to that is instead to not create a generator at all. Use square brackets instead of parentheses when initializing `all_csv` like this: `all_csv = [pd.read_csv(f, sep=',') for f in all_files]`